# SSL certificates not working (AWS Route 53)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, amazon-route53

Because they expired before, I just updated the certificates of a website with DNS in Amazon Route 53 using [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-validate-dns.html). For the new certificate I listed a domain (somedomain.com) and several subdomains (a.somedomain.com , b.somedomain.com).

All the steps described in the tutorial worked and checking on ACM the certificate is already listed as issued. I used the Create record in Route 53 tool in ACS to write the records in Route 53.

[image]

In Route 53's dashboard, the CNAMEs for the new certificate are listed.

However, in ACS, the certificate is listed as not used and, more importantly, my website shows up as having invalid certificates when accessed from a browser.

[image]

Am I missing any step here to update the certificate?

Is there something else needed to make the certificate renewal eligible?

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

ACM can be used with CloudFront/API gateway or ELB/ALB. just issuing a ACM certificate won't do anything, where is your website pointing ? Is it on Load balancer or CloudFront ? You need to use this new ACM certificate there.
What certificate and error do you see when you access your website (e.g: hostname mismatch , cert expired)?

Answer (score 1):

ACM Certificates can only be used with ACM integrated services; in order to use ACM certificates you must be using one of the ACM Integrated services to deliver your site/application to users. You can find our more about ACM integrated services [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-services.html).

A very common use of ACM is for delivering content (or even your full site) via CloudFront, AWS's Content Distribution Network. Note that to use ACM with CloudFront you need to issue your certificate in the us-east-1 region. Once you issue your certificate in us-east-1, you'll be able to attach it to your CloudFront distribution.  You haven't provided any information about your site/application, but in case it's a Wordpress (or really any other CMS managed site), there's a great article about how to setup CloudFront to deliver your site to your  [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/startups/how-to-accelerate-your-wordpress-site-with-amazon-cloudfront/).  If it's a static or single page site/app, you can follow instructions [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/).